# How to exclude transitive jar dependency in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependency-management

My project depends on dependency A and dependency B.

Dependency A also depends on dependency B, but a different version of it.

The problem is in project A's `build.gradle` dependency B is included as a jar directly using the file and fileTree methods:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/B.jar')
}
```

My project's `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.B:B:myvesion'
    compile('com.A:A:theirversion') {
        exclude module: 'B'
    }
}
```

But my build fails with this exception:

```
Execution failed for task ':myproject:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/B/someclass;
```

I want to exclude the `jar` version of B from my project and use my version. How do I do this? Seems like the `exclude` instruction doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Can't you simply change the dependency from using jar B to using the module B as as in `build.gradle`?

Comment: @ahasbini I can do that, but I shouldn't have to downgrade my dependency version because of A. I might be using some newer API available only in my version.

Comment: Gotcha, but the problem is with jars Gradle cannot manage them or their internal dependencies. Meaning even if you switch the dependency in your project `build.gradle` from using the module B to using jar of B, I believe as I'm not entirely sure that it will result with duplicate jars of the same package of B and hence not ignore one of them to end up with throwing a build error as before. Haven't tried that before so would appreciate if you could confirm my theory.

Comment: Just as a side note to further clear things up, `exclude module: 'B'` here is ignored since jar B is not a `pom`-like defined dependency, it is part of A as if it is hardcoded and A does not declare what B is.

Comment: I solved similar problem for Android, may be you can also use this recipe for plain Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63731868/5517503

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it for the jar files.

You can exclude transitive dependencies (described in the pom file). The jar file is not a transitive dependency.