# Excluding jars via Gradle in unit tests

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm including some locally-built libs from another project by using `fileTree()`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

For unit testing, I want to use my own mock classes instead of those jars. How can I have the `testImplementation` configure *not* use those jar files and instead use similarly-named classes out of my source hierarchy?

Comment: `testImplementation('org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.0', {
        exclude group: 'any_group', module: 'any_module
    })`

Comment: Sorry, I think I was confusing by leaving that line in there. I want to keep tests from loading stuff in the jars that `fileTree()` is pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

By default [the `testImplementation` configuration extends from the `implementation` one](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) so every dependency added to `implementation` will be present in `testImplementation`.

So the best option is to declare these specific dependencies into a different configuration, let's call it `extraDeps`, which you then add to the `compileClasspath` configuration:

```
configurations {
    extraDeps
    compileClasspath.extendsFrom(extraDeps)
}

dependencies {
    extraDeps fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This gives you the following advantages:

- Shared dependencies between compile and test can still be in `implementation`
- Special dependencies are identified clearly as they are in their own configuration
- Compile classpath sees all it needs
- Test classpath does not see the special jars

Comment: Seems that the build cannot find the jars: Task :abstraction:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/allen/src/Abstraction/abstraction/src/main/java/com/prometheanworld/abstraction/ktc/Buttons.java:5: error: package com.ktc.button does not exist
import com.ktc.button.PanelButtonsManager;

Comment: Is that an Android build? If that's the case, you may need to add the `extraDeps` configuration as a parent of the relevant Android configurations for compiling, running, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to include aar for implementation and replace it with jar for unit tests. Gradle [can't exclude jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418266/how-to-exclude-transitive-jar-dependency-in-gradle), so I found different solution.

Let's say I have Android project in folder `MyProject`. So there must be files `MyProject/build.gradle` and `MyProject/app/build.gradle`.
I put `<my-dependency>.aar` file and `<my-test-dependency>.jar` files to `MyProject/app/libs` directory. Then I add this directory as local repository in `MyProject/build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can include and exclude my aar by name:

```
configurations.testImplementation {
    exclude module: '<my-dependency>'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: '<my-dependency>', ext:'aar')
    
    testImplementation(name: '<my-test-dependency>', ext:'jar')
    // fileTree also should work, i.e.:
    // testImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```